# django swagger api returned object url instead of readable name

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, swagger, django-admin

I have an model which is for mapping book(item) to categories(tag),
it shows like this in the django admin page.

```
id      item_uid     tag_uid
407     Food         Recipe
```

but in django swagger page, when I try to GET this mapping api with ID 407, it returned like this:

```
"id": 407,
"item_uid": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/237/";
"tag_uid": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/tags/361/"
```

as you can see, it mapped together correctly, but the response body showed the object url and it's object id, which is not readable for human users. I wonder that if there is anyway to make them like this:

```
"id": 407,
"item_uid": "Food";
"tag_uid": "Recipe"
```

edit: codes,

```
#models.py
class Map_item_tag(models.Model):
 item_uid = models.ForeignKey(items, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Item UID')
 tag_uid = models.ForeignKey(tags, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Tag UID')

#admin.py
@admin.register(Map_item_tag)
class map_item_tag_admin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
 resource_class = map_item_tag_Resource
 readonly_fields = ('id',)
 list_display = ['id','item_uid','tag_uid']

#serializers.py
class Map_item_tag_Serializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = Map_item_tag
         fields = ['id','item_uid','tag_uid']

#views.py
class Map_item_tag_ViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    
    queryset = Map_item_tag.objects.all().order_by('item_uid')
    serializer_class = Map_item_tag_Serializer
    parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser)
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

thank you for answering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using a [HyperlinkedModelSerializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#hyperlinkedmodelserializer) instead of a regular [ModelSerializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer)

Try changing the serializer class to a ModelSerializer:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = Item
         fields = [] # list of fields you want to include in your Item serializer

class Map_item_tag_Serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     item_uid = ItemSerializer()
     class Meta:
         model = Map_item_tag
         fields = ['id','item_uid','tag_uid']
```

In addition, I would advise you to use CamelCase notation for all your classes. For example: instead of using `Map_item_tag_Serializer`, change the name to `MapItemTagSerializer`. The same goes for all your other classes.

I would also avoid using using the `_uuid` suffix when using ForeignKey relationships. In the `MapItemTag` model, the ForeignKey relationship inherently means that the field will point to an object `Item` of `Tag` object. Hence, no need to specify the `_uuid` part again.

For example, the following changes would make the model a lot more readable:

```
class MapItemTag(models.Model):
 item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='map_item')
 tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='map_tag')
```

Comment: thank you! your answer works, but now the output looks like this: "id":407, "item":237, "tag":361. I am now trying to find a way to make it readable, btw, thanks for the suggestion, I will try to replace my names to CamelCase later!

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the DRF's [Serializer documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/). It's perfectly possibly to refer to another serializer from within a serializer. I have edited the `Map_item_tag_Serializer` in my answer to reflect  this

Comment: Thank you Woody! much appreciate for your patience. I think I figured it out!